# If f is continuous on [a,b] and $f(x) \geq 0$, for $x \in [a,b]$, but $f$ is not the zero function, prove that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

If f is continuous on [a,b] and $f(x) \geq 0$, for $x \in [a,b]$, but $f$ is not the zero function, prove that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx > 0$

Could anyone give me a hint for this proof please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(c) >0$ then there exists $r>0$ such that $f(x) \geq \frac {f(c)} 2$ for $|x-c| \leq r$. Hence $\int_a^{b} f \geq \int_{c-r}^{c+r} f(x) dx \geq \frac {f(c)} 2 (2r) >0$.

Comment: could you explain by words please?

Comment: I do not understand why $f(x) \geq (f(c)/2)$

Comment: There exists $r$ such that $|f(x)-f(c) |<\frac {f(c)} 2$ for $|x-c| <r$. [ This is because $f$ is continuous at $c$]. Now $f(c) = f(x) +(f(c)-f(x)) < f(x)+ \frac {f(c)} 2$ which gives $f(x) > f(c) -\frac {f(c)} 2 =\frac {f(c)} 2$.

Comment: but why you take $\epsilon $ by this value specifically?

Comment: @hopefully Any $\epsilon$ smaller than $f(c)$ will work fine.

Comment: hence the integral is positive ... correct?

Answer (score 1):

f is not the zero function, and f ≥ 0, so f >0 somewhere. Since f is continuous, f>0 in a tiny interval, then the integral is positive in this interval.